# cannot update android sdk tmp full in kubuntu

Tags: linux, android-studio, ubuntu, android-studio-2.3, tmp

I am using kubuntu 16.04 for about a month now and I wanted to start learning mobile app development using kotlin. I installed android studio, but whenever I try to update my SDK I get an error because my **/tmp runs out of space** and it becomes impossible to download unzip and update the sdk

note:
I have tried tweaking the etc/fstab to resize /tmp.

> tmpfs     /tmp     tmpfs     defaults,size=10G,mode=1777     0     0

tried editing studio.sh

> export _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/tmp

and tried creating a symlink too.

Still no success.